# Using Azure free trial, cannot create resources when I am not the subscription owner

Tags: azure, azure-resource-group

I'm doing some work for a client. They created an Azure Subscription free trial and granted me the Owner role for a resource group.

I'm trying to create an Function App resource, but it is asking me to sign up for my own free trial.

Am I missing some permission or is this a limitation for free trial subscriptions?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this could have been a timing issue. The free trial subscription was created an hour or two before I tried to add a resource. I tried again today, 2 days later, and I am able to provide details for the new Azure Function.

I am now getting another error (see below) prior to the resource getting created. I've researched this, since this is the first time an Azure Function is being added to the subscription, additional changes need to be made at the subscription level that I don't have permissions for.

> Resource provider(s): Microsoft.Web are not registered for
> subscription Free Trial and you don’t have permissions to register a
> resource provider for subscription Free Trial

Here's the article that explains the error:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/error-register-resource-provider

For now, I'll just ask the subscription admin to set up the resource for me.